# React JS form validation logic located in child or parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am not sure I understand how to organize my first React JS application when it comes to things like simple validation logic. My thought was to put as much logic into each child component but it seems to me like when [lifting up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) the more logical place is the parent. But that seems wrong to me since the parent could end up with massive amounts of code for all the children. I've included a real simple example to illustrate the question.

In my sample code there is a small child component for input boxes, a middle component that holds two of these input boxes (let's call it the user name control), and then the top component is an edit page. Each component has it's own version of `isValid`. The lowest child validates that the input isn't empty before being valid. The middle component validates both input boxes have content. The top parent edit page does the same as the middle component. My question is what is the "ideal" place or level to store this simple validation logic?

Thinking ahead to the top level edit page having a simple button that should only be enabled when all validation is checked. Where this confuses me is if you manage many sections on the form with various rules. So not just the user name section needs to be valid but several others as well.

My main confusion is that I think I'm missing something simple because when it comes to the button on the top component (edit page) I do not think the middle component (user control) can communicate it's validation status unless I use a reference. Having read a bit on references it seems like they aren't designed to be overused. If the edit page cannot get feedback from the child user name control on the validation, then the parent needs to do the validation. In the case of a large form that means a lot of validation logic stored in the parent edit page. This might be normal an expected, I'm just not sure.

Can anyone verify of where the "proper" place to put a simple `isValid` check in the scenario I've outlined?

```
class InputBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e);
  }
  render() {
    const inputValue = this.props.value;
    const inputName = this.props.name;
    const isValid = this.props.isValid;
    const label = this.props.label;
    const msg = isValid === true ? 'true' : 'false';
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{label}</span>
        <input type="text"
          name={inputName}
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        <span>Is this textbox valid = {msg}</span>
      </div>
    )}
}
class UserNameControl extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    const controlName = e.target.name;
    const newValue = e.target.value;
    const inputValue1 = controlName === 'input1' ? newValue : this.props.value1;
    const inputValue2 = controlName === 'input2' ? newValue : this.props.value2;
    const isValid = inputValue1 === '' || inputValue2 === '' ? false : true;
    this.props.onChange(controlName,newValue,isValid);
  }
  render() {
    const inputValue1 = this.props.value1;
    const inputValue2 = this.props.value2;
    const isTextValid1 = inputValue1 === '' ? false : true;
    const isTextValid2 = inputValue2 === '' ? false : true;
    const msg1 = isTextValid1 === true ? 'true' : 'false';
    const msg2 = isTextValid2 === true ? 'true' : 'false';
    const isSectionValidMsg = inputValue1 === '' || inputValue2 === '' ? 'false' : 'true';
    const isValid = inputValue1 === '' || inputValue2 === '' ? false : true;
    //this.props.isValid(isValid);
    return (
      <div>
        <div><h2>User Name Control Header</h2></div>
        <InputBox
          label='First Name: '
          name='input1'
          value={inputValue1}
          isValid={isTextValid1}
          onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <br/>
        <InputBox
          label='Last Name: '
          name='input2'
          value={inputValue2}
          isValid={isTextValid2}
          onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <div>
           <h4>User Name Control Footer: Is section valid = {isSectionValidMsg}</h4>
        </div>
       </div>
    )}
}
class EditPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageIsValid: false,
      textValue1: '',
      textValue2: '',
      section1Valid: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.updateSection1Status = this.updateSection1Status.bind(this);
  }
  updateSection1Status(boolValue) {
    this.setState({section1Valid: boolValue});
  }
  handleChange(controlName,inputValue,isSectionValid) {
    this.setState({section1Valid: isSectionValid});
    if(controlName==='input1') {
      this.setState({textValue1: inputValue});
    }
    if(controlName==='input2') {
      this.setState({textValue2: inputValue});
    }
  }

  render() {
    const isFormValid = this.state.textValue1 === '' || this.state.textValue2 === '' ? false : true;
    //const formValidMsg = isFormValid ? 'True' : 'False';
    const formValidMsg = this.state.section1Valid ? 'True' : 'False';
    return (
      <form>
      <h1>Edit Form</h1>
        <div>
          <UserNameControl
            value1={this.state.textValue1}
            value2={this.state.textValue2}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Is form valid = {formValidMsg}</h4>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <EditPage/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right path, the parent should handle most of the validation as this allows the child input to become more generic and therefore more reusable across the application. In this specific scenario, i think the child components should be made as generic as possible, the middle component should handle most of the validation logic, and pass the result up to the parent. In this case however, you will probably need to validate at the parent level also, but honestly, the whole thing could probably be refactored into just two components instead of three. Here is how i would handle your scenario:

```
import React from 'react'

const notEmptyValidation = value => Boolean(value)


const InputBox = props => {
    const {validation, label, name} = props;

    const [localValue, setValue] = React.useState(props.value||"");

    const onChange = e => {
       setValue(e.target.value);
       if(typeof props.onChange === "function"){
         return props.onChange(e) 
      }
     }

    const isValid = () => {
      if(typeof validation === "function"){
         return validation(localValue) 
      }
      return true
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      //this allows the component to be used as either a controlled or uncontrolled input
      setValue(props.value||"")
    }, [props.value])

    return (
      <div>
        <span>{label}</span>
        <input type="text"
          name={name}
          value={localValue}
          onChange={onChange} />
        <span>Is this textbox valid = {`${isValid() ? "true":"false"}`}</span>
      </div>
    )
}

const UserNameControl = props => {

  const [input, setInput] = React.useState({
   input1: "",
   input2: ""
 })

  const onChange = e => {
   let localInput = {...input}; //need to create a new reference to input state
   localInput[e.target.name] = e.target.value
   setInput(localInput)
   if(typeof props.onChange === "function"){ //run the onChange callback from parent
         return props.onChange(localInput) 
     }
  }

  //validates that all values in the input state are populated
  const isValid = () => Object.keys(input).every(key => notEmptyValidation(input[key]))

  return (
      <div>
        <div><h2>User Name Control Header</h2></div>
        <InputBox
          label='First Name: '
          name='input1'
          value={input.inputValue1}
          validation={notEmptyValidation} //pass validation function down to the child
          onChange={onChange}/>
          <br/>
        <InputBox
          label='Last Name: '
          name='input2'
          value={input.inputValue2}
          validation={notEmptyValidation} //pass validation function down to the child
          onChange={onChange}/>
        <div>
           <h4>User Name Control Footer: Is section valid = {`${isValid() ? "true":"false"}`}.</h4>
        </div>
       </div>
    )

}


const EditPage = () => {
  const [userNameData, setUserNameData] = React.useState(null)

  const onChange = inputObj => setUserNameData(inputObj)

  //validates that the input was successful, and all entries are populated
  const isValid = () => userNameData && Object.keys(userNameData).every(key => notEmptyValidation(userNameData[key]))


  return (
      <form>
      <h1>Edit Form</h1>
        <div>
          <UserNameControl onChange={onChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Is form valid = {`${isValid() ? "true":"false"}`}</h4>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <EditPage/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. For some reason I can't get it to work in Codeply so I need to try using my laptop and take a closer look.

Comment: You are right @pretzelb, thanks for pointing that out, i just updated the above example. Here is a working jsfiddle of the example. https://jsfiddle.net/eharris91/273dsbeL/5/

Comment: I actually think it's an issue with CodePly because Jsfiddle seems to not have an issue with your sample. With regards to my question I'm first trying to decipher your code since it uses methods and syntax I haven't encountered yet. Once I do that then I hope I can plan out how it might look in the app I'm building. There's a question that I want to ask but I need to first get a better grasp at what this code is doing and how it could be extended.

Comment: yes, looks like codeply doesnt have support for >ES6 syntax

Comment: I finally got a few minutes to review the code and I think I understand how it works, I just need to now try and apply that to the scenario for my app. I don't think it changes anything for my app that attempts to edit a huge XML file with many complex rules, but I just need a bit of time to plan out a few scenarios with this syntax that is new to me. My guess at this point is that your answer confirmed what I suspected.

Comment: The idea behind the middle component was to try and group related sections of logic that had common rules to make organization easier. However I was not able to see a way let that middle component handle the validation and then push the result "up" to the parent component. That led to the realization that if the parent component was going to manage all the varied section as a whole, it needed to duplicate the same validation logic, which obviously seemed redundant and error prone. Thanks for sharing the code, it was very useful in learning hooks.